# How to adjust height of sound strip in VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have one sound strip in my blender file. But it has a small height, so if I make the height of the Video Sequence Editor panel small, the waveform in the tiny sound strip is compressed vertically so much that it cannot be seen.

I want to make the VSE panel thin, but make the sound strip fill its height, so I can see the sound waveform.

The VSE is showing 6 channels, but I only need one. Can I remove the other channels from the VSE? Maybe that would expand my sound strip vertically?

How do I get the waveform to be visible in a VSE with small height? I've searched the Web; nothing found.

Answer (score 3):

In the strips portion of the VSE, click and drag the MMB to move the view, Ctrl click and move the MMB to resize.
Don't forget to activate the "Draw waveforems" option.

[image]

Comment: I can't always get this to work. Are there any other ways to do this? I clicked the Home key in the wrong place and my strip collapsed to a thick line. Then I tried to expand it and the line moved out of range so I can't see it.

Comment: Also, the Draw Waveform checkbox does not appear under Sound. See screenshot. How to add the screenshot?

Comment: How to use the vertical scroll bar at the left of the VSE?

Comment: Which version are you using? Did you change any default behaviours (like left/right click, or scrolll wheel direction, .....)? If you click on the center of the scroll bars (on the left and on the bottom side of the window) you can pan over the sequencer strips, if you click on the side (dots) of the scroll bars, they act as zoom.

Comment: Version 2.79b. I changed left/right click because of nonstandard behavior of Blender, I changed colors to always show selection in red, I changed to numloc mode because my computer has no numloc. That's all. I can get the strip height correct (filling the panel) by trial and error using various methods, but it is awkward. Would be better if could be done automatically by Blender or at least preserved when the panel height is changed (one has to change the panel height to insert new editors when needed, such as dope sheet and timeline). It is very hard to describe the problems exactly.